# mysql system variable table_type doesn't work

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am unable to set the system variable table_type. When I try to do so I get the following error.

```
mysql> SET table_type=InnoDB;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'table_type'
```

I see that "table_type" is not listed when I do a "SHOW VARIABLES". Is this a setup issue?

To install mysql I just did a "sudo yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-libs" on Amazon EC2 instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_type):

> This variable was removed in MySQL 5.5.3. Use [storage_engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine) instead.

Which in turn says:

> This variable is deprecated as of MySQL 5.5.3. Use [default_storage_engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_storage_engine)  instead.

Therefore you should use `SET default_storage_engine=InnoDB`, which FWIW is the default since MySQL 5.5.5.

Answer (score -1):

pls try this one

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```