# Ejabberd roster with mysql

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using exauth with ejabberd to authenticate my users, but I want to use mysql to store user information, such as GROUPS, rosters etc.

Here is my configuration.

```
{auth_method, external}.
{extauth_program, "/home/hitesh/ejabberd_auth.php"}.

{host_config, "subdomain.nodyssey.com", [{auth_method, [external, anonymous]}]}.

{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost","ejabberd", "root", "root"}}.
```

the mysql database is EMPTY! users still have roster and chat history on group chat,so looks like mnesia database is being used! How do I switch to mysql for this?

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you create the mysql database? were you previously using mnesia for roster? if so did you migrate the data? last thing, did you enable in ejabberd.cfg mod_roster_odbc?

Comment: @user601836 how do I do that? {mod_roster_odbc,[]} like this?

Comment: yes, plus disable mod_odbc...of course you need all the modules needed for mysql connection

Comment: ok, mod_odbc is disabled, mysql connection is working, mysql modules are uploaded and working fine. But still its using mynesia database! 

here is my config, https://gist.github.com/hiteshjoshi/5117477 ,

Comment: sorry. i meant you have to disable mod_roster..not mod_odbc...mod_roster enabled means roster support with mnesia.

Comment: Hey @Hitesh,Can you show me the details for ejabberd_auth.php, which you have included in configuration file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

user601836's correct. I misunderstood the question initially. Assuming that odbc and mysql driver are properly installed, here is the updated answer:

1. Have you created the mysql tables to store the roster data, etc? Also are all of your ejabberd tables created using innodb engine? 
   You can get the schema in github: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/2.1.x/src/odbc/mysql.sql. Also you can find it in your ejabberd installation folder. Mine is in this location: ejabberd_installation_root/lib/ejabberd-2.1.11/priv/sql/mysql.sql.
2. Replace related module names using the *_odbc one in your ejabberd.cfg. For example, replace mod_roster to mod_roster_odbc, replace mod_muc to mod_muc_odbc. A number of odbc supported modules are listed here:

   ```
   ...
   {mod_offline_odbc,  []},
   {mod_last_odbc,     []},
   {mod_roster_odbc,   []},
   {mod_shared_roster_odbc,[]},
   {mod_vcard_odbc,    []},
   {mod_muc_odbc, [
     ...]},
   {mod_pubsub_odbc, [
     ...]},
   ...
   ```

For the detailed module information, check the official doc:

```
https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#modoverview
```

Comment: AFAIK authentication method doesn't affect rostering in ejabberd

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the question. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, this looks like promising answer. Also, do you think all *_odbc modules are already installed? or Do I need to install them again?

Also, when I run the MYSQL script, my MySql Server doesnt accept this, "SET table_type=InnoDB;" so I removed it and installed rest of SQL command, is it going to work? If not then how do I install mysql with innodb! Sorry, another question this is. But if you can help.

Comment: By default all *_odbc are installed. However, if you manually install ejabberd, you have to specify the "--enable-odbc" option.

Comment: You'd better use innodb. Not sure what will happen if it's myisam engine. You can run "show create table one_of_the_ejabberd_table_name;" to see if the storage engine is innodb. My guess is that you are using MySQL 5.5, which doesn't have the table_type variable any more. See the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517323/mysql-system-variable-table-type-doesnt-work

Comment: If all of your ejabberd tables are already innodb. You are safe.

Comment: @HiteshJoshi : is it possible to get roster information from a custom MySQL schema and not ejabberd.sql?

Comment: @DarkHorse Yes, should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since this question was asked. Ejabberd configuration file has changed in meantime. To enable external roster storage, assuming that ejabberd and mysql DB and ejabberd schema are configured, all you have to do in ejabberd.yml is this:

```
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "some_database_name"
sql_username: "some_username"
sql_password: "some_password"
```

and to change `mod_roster: {}`

to

```
mod_roster:
   db_type: sql
```