# Creating tables failed

Tags: mysql

I have installed mySQL Server and created a user called `ej_instance` and has set password "password". Logged into server using below command

```
  mysql -u ej_instance -p;
  -- entered password
```

ej_instance has access to only `ejabberd` database. So I executed command like below

```
  use ejabberd;
```

Then tried to execute commands like below

```
  SET table_type=InnoDB;

  CREATE TABLE users (
     username varchar(250) PRIMARY KEY,
     password text NOT NULL,
     created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

But it is throwing errors at me. Below are errors

```
  ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'table_type'
  ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

How can get this done? anything else to be changed?

Comment: after you do the use ejabberd; does it say 'Database changed'?

Comment: Try adding `user ejabberd` into the script you are trying to execute.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes it has logged the same. `Database changed`

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I am already logged in as `ej_instance`. `ejabberd` is the database name.

Comment: What version of mysql are you running?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517323/mysql-system-variable-table-type-doesnt-work

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for the response instead I had set SET storage_engine=InnoDB it worked.

Comment: If your wondering why it worked check the link i posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the engine type when creating the table, like this:

```
USE ejabberd;

CREATE TABLE users (
     username varchar(250) PRIMARY KEY,
     password text NOT NULL,
     created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE = INNODB;
```

If the use error still showing, check:

1. the database exists
2. the user ej_instance has privileges to access and create tables on the database

Loggin as root:

```
#check the database exists
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'ejabberd';

#check user permissions
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ej_instance'@'localhost';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ej_instance'@'%';
```

If don't have enough permissions:

```
#grant all permission on the user for the specified database
GRANT ALL ON ejabberd.* TO 'ej_instance'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON ejabberd.* TO 'ej_instance'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response instead I had set `SET storage_engine=InnoDB` it worked.

Comment: I usually make it faster, means before even asked :)